# How to dynamically update an attribute in a dynamodb item?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, crud

I created an item in dynamodb using Node js, the item has multiple attributes such as brand, category, discount, validity, etc. I am using uuid to generate ids for each item. Now let's say I want to update the validity attribute of the item, in which case I am currently sending the entire json object with the value of validity modified to the new value.

This is definitely not optimal, please help me find an optimal solution.

```
const params = {
    TableName: process.env.PRODUCT_TABLE,
    Key: {
      id: event.pathParameters.id,
    },
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      '#discount': 'discount',
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':brand': data.brand,
      ':category': data.category,
      ':discount': data.discount,
      ':denominations': data.denominations,
      ":validity": data.validity,
      ":redemption": data.redemption    
    },
    UpdateExpression: 'SET #discount = :discount, denominations = :denominations, brand = :brand, category = :category, validity = :validity, redemption = :redemption',
    ReturnValues: 'ALL_NEW',
  };
```

I want to send just the attribute I want to update with the new value, if I want to change the validity from 6 months to 8 months, I should just send something like:
{
    "validity": "8 months"
}
And it should update the validity attribute of the item.
Same should apply to any other attribute of the item.

```
'use strict';

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

module.exports.update = (event, context, callback) => {
  const data = JSON.parse(event.body);

  let attr = {};
  let nameobj = {};
  let exp = 'SET #';
  let arr = Object.keys(data);
  let attrname = {};

  arr.map((key) => {attr[`:${key}`]=data[key]});

  arr.map((key) => {
    exp += `${key} = :${key}, `
  });

  arr.map((key) => {nameobj[`#${key}`]=data[key]});

  attrname = {
    [Object.keys(nameobj)[0]] : nameobj[Object.keys(nameobj)[0]]
  }

  const params = {
    TableName: process.env.PRODUCT_TABLE,
    Key: {
      id: event.pathParameters.id,
    },
    ExpressionAttributeNames: attrname,
    ExpressionAttributeValues: attr,
    UpdateExpression: exp,
    ReturnValues: 'ALL_NEW',
  };

  // update the todo in the database
  dynamoDb.update(params, (error, result) => {
    // handle potential errors
    if (error) {
      console.error(error);
      callback(null, {
        statusCode: error.statusCode || 501,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' },
        body: 'Couldn\'t update the card',
      });
      return;
    }

    // create a response
    const response = {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(result.Attributes),
    };
    callback(null, response);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 34):

Contrary to others comments, this is very possible, use the **UpdateItem** action.

[Language agnostic API docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html)

[JavaScript specific API docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#updateItem-property)

If you want to dynamically create the query, try something like this:

```js
function GenerateUpdateExpression(object) {
    let exp = {
        UpdateExpression: 'set',
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {},
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {}
    };
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object)) {
        exp.UpdateExpression += ` #${key} = :${key},`;
        exp.ExpressionAttributeNames[`#${key}`] = key;
        exp.ExpressionAttributeValues[`:${key}`] = value;
    };
    // remove trailing comma
    exp.UpdateExpression = exp.UpdateExpression.slice(0, -1);
    return exp
}

let data = {
    'field' : { 'subfield': 123 },
    'other': '456'
}

let expression = GenerateUpdateExpression(data)

let params = {
    // Key, Table, etc..
    ...expression
}

console.log(params)
```

Output:

```js
{ 
    UpdateExpression: 'set #field = :field, #other = :other',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        '#field': 'field',
        '#other': 'other'
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':field': { 
            'subfield': 123
        },
        ':other': '456'
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this Richard! I'm surprised about the lack of code examples for using the JS Dynamo SDK

Comment: No problem. I might update that answer later as I think I have a slightly better version somewhere. You're right, there's not a lot in the way of examples, but the docs are fairly decent once you know what you're looking for. I've been using Dynamo for a while and I've learned most big lessons through trial and error. That said, it's my go-to DB now, unless there's strong case for using something else. They do leave a lot of responsibility with the developer, which is hard a first, but it also means you can pretty much master the whole API before long and keep all your logic in one language.

Comment: Ah excellent, I was just about to write this out myself, thanks for the saved time!

Answer (score 0):

### Using Javascript SDK V3:

Import from the right package:

```
import { DynamoDBClient PutItemCommandInput, UpdateItemCommandInput, UpdateItemCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb';
```

Function to dynamically do partial updates to the item:
(the code below is typescript can be easily converted to Javascript, just remove the types!)

```
function updateItem(id: string, item: any) {
  const dbClient = new DynamoDBClient({region: 'your-region-here });

  let exp = 'set ';
  let attNames: any = { };
  let attVal: any = { };
  for(const attribute in item) {
    const valKey = `:${attribute}`;
    attNames[`#${attribute}`] = attribute;
    exp += `#${attribute} = ${valKey}, `;     
    const val = item[attribute]; 
    attVal[valKey] = { [getDynamoType(val)]: val };
  }

  exp = exp.substring(0, exp.length - 2);

  const params: UpdateItemCommandInput = {
    TableName: 'your-table-name-here',
    Key: { id: { S: id } },
    UpdateExpression: exp,
    ExpressionAttributeValues: attVal,
    ExpressionAttributeNames: attNames,
    ReturnValues: 'ALL_NEW',
  };

  try {
    console.debug('writing to db: ', params);
    const command = new UpdateItemCommand(params);
    const res = await dbClient.send(command);
    console.debug('db res: ', res);
    return true;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('error writing to dynamoDB: ', err);
    return false;
  }
}
```

And to use it (we can do partial updates as well):

```
updateItem('some-unique-id', { name: 'some-attributes' });
```

Answer (score 0):

What i did is create a `helper class`.

- Here is a simple function : Add all the attribute and values that goes into, if the value is null or undefined it won't be in the expression.
- I recommande to create a `helper class` with `typescript` and add more functions and other stuff like generator of `expressionAttributeValues` , `expressionAttributeNames` ... , Hope this help.

```js
function updateExpression(attributes, values) {
  const expression = attributes.reduce((res, attribute, index) => {

    if (values[index]) {
      res += ` #${attribute}=:${attribute},`;
    }

    return res;
  }, "SET ");

  return expression.slice(0, expression.length - 1)
}

console.log(
  updateExpression(["id", "age", "power"], ["e8a8da9a-fab0-55ba-bae3-6392e1ebf624", 28, undefined])
);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use code and generate the params object based on the object you provide. It's just a JavaScript object, you walk through the items so that the update expression only contains the fields you have provided.
This is not really a DynamoDB question in that this is more a general JS coding question.

Comment: From JS side it can be done obviously, but I was thinking if dynamodb provides some kind of update expression to do the same.

Comment: Okay, then the short answer is no. :) But to be fair, this is also the case in SQL, only supply the parameters you want to use. In general though there are much less comfort functions in DynamoDB, I have worked with SQL server and Oracle for years and especially the latter has a lot of nice little extra's.

Comment: I tried to do that, I posted my code above. Can you check and tell me what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: I guess the problem is missing #. You need to add `#` in front of all the fields names. Exp should look something like this in the end
 `#k1 = :v1, #k2 = :v2`

Comment: The code snippet on the top is from a working version, in that I only used the '#' symbol before the first variable.

Answer (score -2):

You can use UpdateItem; to familiarize yourself with DynamoDb queries I would suggest you DynamoDb NoSQL workbench:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/workbench.settingup.html

It can generate snippets for you based on your queries.

[DynamoDb NoSQL workbench screenshot query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlBWM.png)

Comment: I think this is the same answer as Richard’s?

Comment: no because it doesn't tell you to use DynamoDb  workbench which can do the heavy lifting for you?