# How to store multiple message in same row with AWS iot and dynamodbv2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, mqtt, aws-iot

I am using AWS Iot core and dynamodbv2 to store my mqtt message.

My table Primary partition key  `deviceId`
and Rule query statement as

`SELECT *, topic(2) AS deviceId FROM 'device/+'`   .

The first message publish`{"deviceId": "Name1","temperature":25}`.

The table store like:

```
deviceId    temperature 
Name1       25
```

When I publish the second message
`{"deviceId": "Name1","setpoint":23}`,

It will replace the previous message.

```
deviceId    setpoint 
Name1       23
```

I want to publish message separately. Is it possible to keep the previous message and store the both message like that? Thanks.

```
deviceId    temperature    setpoint 
Name1       25             23
```

Comment: You need to modify the second input and make it `{"deviceId": "Name1","temperature":25,"setpoint":23}` - how are you putting it in DDB?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I created the rule in aws Iot [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-ddb-rule.html). If I would like to publish separately, can I still possible to store message together? Thanks

Comment: @Nakamoto if any of the provided answers helped you to solve your problem, please consider upvoting them. You can even pick the answer that solved your problem as the accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-ddb-rule.html) you mentioned and the way the system behaves, it looks like the [PutItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html) method is used to insert elements into DynamoDB. Meaning new items will overwrite old items if an item with the same primary key already exists.

The problem here is, that your `deviceId` is a bad primary key as it is not unique. You expect to have more than one entry with primary key `Name1` which is not possible. Instead, I suggest to adjust your SQL statement to get a unique key. This key could be generated with the [timestamp()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sql-functions.htm) or [traceid()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sql-functions.htm) functions of AWS IoT Core. Your SQL could the look ike this:

```sql
SELECT *, 
       topic(2) AS deviceId, 
       timestamp() as timestamp, 
       traceid() as traceId 
FROM 'device/+'
```

Then you use the `timestamp` or `traceId` or a compound key made up of `timestamp`+`deviceId` for instance as your **primary key**. The `deviceId` can be used as the **sort key**. This is also how it was described in the tutorial

> - `sample_time` is a **primary key** and describes the time the sample was recorded.
> - `device_id` is a **sort key** and describes the device that provided the sample
> - `device_data` is the data received from the device and formatted by the rule query statement

Be aware, that you cannot store the data like this

```
deviceId    temperature    setpoint 
Name1       25             23
```

unless your MQTT message containts temperature and setpoint. Otherwise they will always be stored separately.

The only "workaround" to store the data as you described is to write a small lambda that uses [PutItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html) to store the data if none exists and [UpdateItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html) to add "setpoint" or "temperature" to an already existing item. You could, most likely, even do without PutItem as UpdateItem:

> Edits an existing item's attributes, or **adds a new item** to the table if it does not already exist. You can put, delete, or add attribute values. You can also perform a conditional update on an existing item (insert a new attribute name-value pair if it doesn't exist, or replace an existing name-value pair if it has certain expected attribute values).

If you are fine with only keeping the latest value of "temperature" and "setpoint" this set up is fine. If you need to keep a history of how the "temperature" changed over time then you should either add a timestamp to your message or use the SQL `timestamp()` function and use the timestamp as or as part of your primary key. In case you plan to have a lot, and I mean a lot, of devices sending their data to AWS IoT then the timestamp may not be good enough as a primary key and you need to have a compound made up by the timestamp and deviceId to keep it unique.

A great introduction on how DynamoDB works, partition keys, sort keys, indexes and more can be found in [this video of Marcia Villalba](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tb8Cw3TUDRM).

Comment: Thanks mate, I tried lambda and found the solution in here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55825544/how-to-dynamically-update-an-attribute-in-a-dynamodb-item/59194533#59194533)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using the dynamoDB [PutItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html) method, that replaces a item if the same primary key is found.

According the Aws DynamoDB [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html) the PutItem method:

> Creates a new item, or replaces an old item with a new item (including all the attributes). If an item already exists in the specified table with the same primary key, the new item completely replaces the existing item. You can perform a conditional put (insert a new item if one with the specified primary key doesn't exist), or replace an existing item if it has certain attribute values.

To ensure that a new item **does not replace an existing item, use a conditional put** operation with `Exists` set to false.

For understand how to do this using Node.js take a look [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#putItem-property).